# Minimal Hamming distance subvector

Tags: string, algorithm, time-complexity, suffix-tree, hamming-distance

Let `U`  small alphabet `0, 1` or `A, C, G, T`, `k <= n`.

I want to find minimum Hamming distance between 
`u = (u_1,...,u_k)` and the contiguous subsequences of `v = (v_1,...,v_n)` of length `k`
in time `O(n log n)`.

Is it possible?

Thank you for any help!

Comment: If this allows preprocessing of `v`, what would be the limits on time and space? Without considering `k` fixed, it may show up in the function describing the growth of complexity with problem size. See, for example, [Wikipedia on optimal string alignment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hirschberg's_algorithm). (Salutations and aTdHvAaNnKcSe are not welcome here.)

Comment: No, `k` not fixed. 

For example if `k = n/2` then time in Hirschberg's algorithm is `O(n^2)`

Answer (score 1):

For the alphabet `{1, -1}`, multiply the polynomials

```
(u_k + u_{k-1} x + u_{k-2} x^2 + ... + u_1 x^{k-1})
```

and

```
(v_1 + v_2 x + v_3 x^2 + ... + v_n x^{n-1}).
```

The coefficient of `x^i` in the product is a simple affine function of the Hamming distance between `u_1 ... u_k` and `v_{i-k+2} ... v_{i+1}`.

We can encode other alphabets by embedding them to make the Hamming distances work out, e.g.,

```
A -> 0000
C -> 0011
G -> 0101
T -> 1001.
```